# how to change file names to their default with powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I just wanted to re-number my music files based on their date creation on windows 10 and I found this PowerShell script on the internet.

```
[ref]$i = 1; gci -file | Rename-Item -NewName {'{0:D} - {1}' -f $i.Value++, $_}
```

but this code didn't do that.
After that, I used the below code but unfortunately, my file names were broken and converted to numbers! see the code and image below

```
$count = 1; Get-ChildItem -File | Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Rename-Item -NewName { '{0:D {1}' -f $script:count++, $_.Extension }
```

[image]

So now I want to **first** rename my files to their default name and after that, I would like to re-number them by their date of creation. For example, if assuming my latest song is "song1.mp3" it should turn to "1 - song1.mp3".

Tnx a lot.

Comment: How are you planning to get their default name ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I'm hoping there will be a way to get their default name back. I think PowerShell could do that base on the details of each file. Am I right?

Comment: If the "default names" are embedded in the files metadata then yes you could, probably

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Yes, they have embedded in the file's metadata.

Comment: This seems like a good place to start then: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/list-music-file-metadata-in-a-csv-and-open-in-excel-with-powershell/

Comment: I think it would be best for you to try a freeware file renaming utility like Ant Renamer or Advanced File Renamer (just google for lots more) so you can first see what the result would be (and some even have an undo option)  instead of blindly running scripts from the internet on your files.

Comment: @Theo tnx. I have used Advance File Renamer and that solves my problem. Thanks a lot.